# Excel VBA array to populate tables

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

My current code will search column A for a specific string name in worksheet named "Temp". From there the code will copy over matching rows to worksheet "Table1" and save the output to my desktop.

```
    Sub Find_Team()
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range, firstAddress As String
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Const strFindMe As String = "Team A"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Temp")
        Set rngData = .Range("A3:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table1")

    With rngData
        Set rngFound = .Find(strFindMe, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = rngFound.Address
            Do
                rngFound.EntireRow.Copy
                wsNew.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
                Set rngFound = .FindNext(rngFound)
            Loop While Not rngFound Is Nothing And rngFound.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

     Call SavSheets
End Sub

Sub SavSheets()
Dim InitFileName As String, fileSaveName As String

fileSaveName = "C:Desktop\ " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
Worksheets(Array("Table 1", "Table 2", "Table 3", "Table 4", "Table 5", "Table 6", "Table 7", "Table 8")).Copy      
Set wbNew = ActiveWorkbook
With wbNew
 .SaveAs fileSaveName
  .Close
End With
End Sub
```

What I would like for this code to accomplish is to read in a list of Team names and loop to complete the steps above.

I did find code that will give me a distinct list of names that are in my worksheet Temp column A1 that I would need.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

```
Sub Unique_Names()
Dim X
Dim objDict As Object
Dim lngRow As Long
Sheets("Temp").Select
Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
X = Application.Transpose(Range([A1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)))

For lngRow = 1 To UBound(X, 1)
    objDict(X(lngRow)) = 1
Next
Range("N1:N" & objDict.Count) = Application.Transpose(objDict.keys)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give each sheet the name of a team you can use autofilter:

```
Sub M_snb()
 for each sh in sheets
  if sh.name<>"temp" then
    with sheets("temp").cells(1).currenregion
      .autofilter 1, sh.name
      .copy sh.cells(1)
      .autofilter
    end with
  end if
 next
end sub
```